# Why git rebase shows conflicts in the files I did not modify?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Let's say that I am on a local repo and its branch is `my_name/branch_A`

When I do `git rebase <branch_B>`, I sometimes get many conflicts in the files that I did not modify.

Why does this happen? 
I like to just get the HEAD of all the files from `branch_B` except for the ones I modified in `my_name/branch_A`. How can this be done without manually resolving these conflicts that I did not introduce myself.

Comment: If there are modified files in that branch, then there is potential for conflicts. It does not matter if you or someone else modified them. In order to rebase, you have to tell git what to do about those conflicting modifications. If you just want to keep the versions from branch_a, then you can choose that option during conflict resolution (for example using an interactive rebase).

Answer (score 34):

Rebase *copies* commits (and then abandons the originals).  This is the root of the problem.

Let's look at an example.  First, note that I'm drawing commit graphs with older commits towards the left, and newer commits towards the right.  The commits have single-letter names here, instead of Git's true 40-character hash names like `f1c93ab7...`.  Branch names appear on the right, with an arrow pointing to the *tip commit* of that branch, because that is how Git actually stores these things.

Your current branch name is `my_name/branch_A`, and you have a branch named `branch_B` as well.  There are some commits on each branch that are not on the other branch, and some commits that are on *both* branches.  Meanwhile your branch, `my_name/branch_A`, forks off from some third point—so there are commits on your branch that are not on `branch_B`, but are not "your commits":

```
...--A--B--C--D--E         <-- branch_uhoh
         \        \
          \        I--J    <-- my_name/branch_A
           \
            F--G--H        <-- branch_B
```

You made commits `I` and `J` and now you would like to have those two commits come after commit `H`, i.e., to rework your commits to be "after" the tip of `branch_B`.

In other words, you *did not* make commits `C--D--E`.  Nonetheless, these commits are on your branch.  In fact, commits `A` and `B` are on your branch too: those two commits are on *all* the branches.

If you now run `git rebase branch_B` (while you're still on your branch), Git has to figure out two things:

- what to copy, and
- where to start putting the copies.

The name `branch_B` tells Git *both of these things*.  The commits to be copied are "those that are on `my_name/branch_A` but not on `branch_B`.  That's `C-D-E-I-J`.  The place to put them is "after the tip commit of `branch_B`, i.e., after commit `H`.

If this all succeeds, Git would set your branch name to point to the new copies:

```
...--A--B--C--D--E         <-- branch_uhoh
         \        \
          \        I--J    [abandoned]
           \
            F--G--H        <-- branch_B
                   \
                    C'-D'-E'-I'-J'  <-- my_name/branch_A
```

The names with the "prime" marks (`C'` and so on) are the copies.

(You can view the commits that `git rebase` would/will copy with `git log <upstream>..HEAD`, which in this case is `git log branch_B..HEAD`.  I would add `--oneline` here in most cases to get a one-line log message per commit.)

Well, if that's the problem, what should you do?  The obvious answer is: tell Git not to copy `C-D-E`.  You *want* this result instead:

```
...--A--B--C--D--E         <-- branch_uhoh
         \        \
          \        I--J    [abandoned]
           \
            F--G--H        <-- branch_B
                   \
                    I'-J'  <-- my_name/branch_A
```

That is, Git should copy only those commits "between" (after, really) the tip of `branch_uhoh` and your branch, so as to get commits `I` and `J`; but it should copy them *to* (again, after, really) the tip of `branch_B`.  The way to do that is to write:

```
git rebase --onto branch_B branch_uhoh
```

In other words, tell rebase *both* things, instead of telling it *one* thing and letting it figure out the two from that.

(But how do you find `branch_uhoh`?  Well, the "right" way is usually to *remember* it, but you can just run `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` and find the cutoff commit by its ID or any name that shows up.  Instead of `branch_uhoh` you can cut-and-paste the hash ID of the actual cutoff commit.  Most often, you can have *Git itself* remember the "upstream" name for you, and you rebase only within and onto the upstream and you need *no* arguments: you just run `git rebase` and it does all the work.  But there are special cases where you need to transplant commits, where this is not sufficient; then you need `git rebase --onto`.)

Comment: It may be helpful to mention that the commits applied by `git rebase <upstream>` can be viewed using `git log <upstream>..HEAD`.

Comment: @torek Thank you for your detailed explanation. After I did `git rebase --onto branch_B some_hash_ID`, I do see that my commits I want to copy are onto the HEAD of `branch_B`. I confirmed it by doing `git log --graph --decorate --oneline`. 


However, my local workspace does not reflect this. So, if I do `git push --force` it will overwrite the remote repo to totally wrong state. 


How can I make my local workspace point to the HEAD of `my/branch_A` and push it to the remote repo?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "local workspace". In Git's terms, the three storage areas are: your repository itself (your commits and what is in them, and the branch and tag or "reference" labels and which commits they point-to); the index or staging area, which represents what will go into your *next* commit; and your "work tree" or "working tree": the files you edit so that you can `git add` them to your index so that you can `git commit` to make the next commit.

Comment: One other thing that might help you look at the state of your own repository: try `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` (i.e., add `--all`). Or you can use a graphical viewer like `gitk --all`, or one of the GUIs, for visualizing the complete graph.

Comment: Finally, note that when you `git push` without giving `push` additional arguments, what gets pushed depends on both your Git version, and any setting you have chosen for `push.default`. So to predict what `git push --force` would do we need to know which version of Git you have, your `push.default`, and your current branch.